# unescape string to hex values in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am generating the following string with JavaScript:

```
"ISCP\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x09\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\!1PWR01\x0D\x0A"
```

It represents a chain of text and Hex values.

In fact the actual underlying string is built up like this:

```
"ISCP\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x10\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x09\\x01\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\!1PWR01\\x0D\\x0A"
```

As I have to escape the slashes to be able to work with them in the first place.

Now I have to somehow transform this string into a into a string of chained Hex values so that I can send it across a TCP connection.
The result would look something like this:

```
\x49\x53\x43\x50\0\0\0\x10\0\0\0\t\x01\0\0\0\0\x21\x31\x50\x57\x52\x30\x31\r\n
```

But I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: if those are really hex values, then the string does NOT have literal ``\``, `x`, `0`, 0` characters in it. it'll be a single character with that hex value. escaping the slashes means that your string doesn't contain hex values. it contains string representations of hex values.

Comment: It might be more clear to say "the **string literal** used to build this string value is `"ISCP\\x00\\x00..."`". The first block has your string *value*, and the second has the string *literal* used to create that value. And for your final block, you could say "I want to produce a string *as if it were created by the literal* `"\x49\x53\x43..."`"

Comment: I guess my vocabulary was not sufficient....learning every day! But yes, that is what I mean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to find all the `\xHH`-style sequences in your string and replace them with actual values. Since you cannot dynmically create literal `\xHH` escape sequences, you'll need to use a replacer callback with `String.fromCharCode`:

```
var newString = myString.replace(/\\x([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/g, function(m, g1) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(g1, 16));
});
```

This parses the two digits following each `\x` as a base-16 value, and then uses that number as a character code to create a new one-character string.

Comment: At first, the 'm' and g1 parameters puzzled me, but looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace helped. The 'm' is an arbitrary name for the matched substring, and the 'g1' denotes the part of the regex that the match pertains to (the first and only part in this case) and also contains that matched substing.